# How to configure hot deploy in eclipse maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a maven project on eclipse, but when i restart the tomcat server inside eclipse, changes are not reflected on my app.
I´d try to do two tests:

First - make some changes on a single javascript file and restart tomcat, and works great.

Second - make some changes on a java class and restart tomcat, and nothing has change on my browser.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to configure your tomcat to hot deploy your application.
http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

Follow this tut.